# Error: ./node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.js 1448:12-20 "export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

i have updated my angular project from version 6 to version 11 but this error was displayed

```
 Error: ./node_modules/angular-font-awesome/dist/angular-font-awesome.js 1448:12-20       "export 'Renderer' was not found in '@angular/core'
```

Comment: See: https://angular.io/guide/migration-renderer

Comment: i don't understand what can i do

Comment: Please update the question with your package.json too